# How do I set the absolute position of a WPF GeometryDrawing?

Tags: wpf

How do I set the absolute position of a GeometryDrawing?
Currently the line is always drawn in the center.
I guess the LineGeometery is always following the Alignments on Image control.

Here is some (now edited) code I am working with:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfProblem.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"   >
<Grid Width="450" Height="160" Background="Beige" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Border BorderBrush="Lime" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="80" Background="#1AFF0000" Margin="0">
        <Image Width="420" Height="120" Stretch="None" >
            <Image.Source>
                <DrawingImage>
                    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,30" EndPoint="299,30"/>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <Pen Thickness="5" Brush="Black"/>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                </DrawingImage>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just set the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties you already have defined on the `<Image>` tag?

Comment: Canvas.Top & Left do not help. The problem is the the LineGeometery is being aligned in the Image contol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Vertical & HorizontalAlignment affects the internal drawing of a DrawImage. So depending on VerticalAlignment, a single horizontal line will be drawn at the top, center, or bottom of the final Image.  I am now embedding the Drawing in a FrameworkElement with the needed absolute positioning.

Corrected per Liz's comment.

Comment: I assume you mean vertical alignment

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem (aside from the code above that does not compile, since Image.Source does not have Width and Height attributes) isn't that your GeometryDrawing is centered, it's that your Canvas is centered.

To prove it, just make the Background of your Canvas Red:

```
<Canvas Width="350" Height="180" Background="Red">
```

Your GeometryDrawing is at the appropriate position within this centered Canvas.

[image: Geometry Drawing Example]

If you want the Canvas to fit the entire window, don't set explicit width and height, set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to Stretch:

```
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Background="Blue">
```

to get:
[image: Stretch Canvas]

Comment: Even using your suggestion, the line is still being centered in the Image control.

Comment: Hmmm...I copied your original code, made it compilable, and made the changes I suggested to produce the screen shots above.  I won't have access to that code for a week or so, but I see that you are still setting absolute sizes.  Post screen shots of what your code produces, making sure to match the screen shot with any edits.

Comment: Think about it, if the container does not have an absolute height of 120 how could it possible know that a horizontal line at 30 should be drawn exactly 1/4 the container size down.  Without the 120 reference, the 30 is just a random number.

Comment: No, 30 is always 30. Relative to the top of the container, not random. Will your window always be the same size? Absolute sizes are ok if that is really what you want (I don't know your requirements), but generally speaking, WPF is usually done using relative sizing. If you want something to be 1/4 down the container, you can do so by setting the values in the SizeChanged event in the code-behind.

Comment: Please post a screen shot.  I haven't actually tested it this time, but I believe your Image is being centered, not your drawing.  Set the Horizontal and Vertical Alignments on the Image (Left and Top if you want to use absolute sizes, Stretch if you want to fill the container).

Answer (score 0):

If you change Stretch="None" to Stretch="Fill"  on your Image it will use the whole space.  It won't fill up the whole size of the border, because you have specified a height and width.

Now if you use a GeometryGroup you can specify as many types of lines, paths, whatever.  This will then be stretched to fill your image space.

```
<GeometryGroup>
    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="410,0"/>
    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0, 100" EndPoint="410, 0"/>
</GeometryGroup>
```

The lines will be drawn to "fit" your image.
Which is a little closer to what you want, I think.  Leaving the the Stretch to None, will draw the objects at the center of the image, and will not stretch them when the image is re-sized.

That seems to be the two alternatives of using the ImageDrawing, either center, or draw to fit.

Comment: The problem is not with the placement of the Image. It is that the line is aligned in the Image control. I want the to be drawn with no alignment.

Comment: That doesn't change the placement of the image at all, it "describes how an Image should be stretched to fill the destination rectangle".  I played with this a little more, and am updating my answer, although I still don't know if this will fully answer your question.